# How do I catch a specific try statement in a do block with multiple try statements Swift 2.0

Tags: try-catch, swift2

```
do {
    try thingOne()
    try thingTwo()
    try manager.removeItemAtPath("myPath") //NSFileManager instance
} catch ThingOneErrorType.SomeError {
    //code here
} catch { 
    //Need to respond explicitly to manager.removeItemAtPath but how?
}
```

I'm using NSFileManager removeItemAtPath instance method within a do block that contains multiple try statements and I want to explicitly catch the error that comes from the fileManager. My problem is that if I review the [docs for NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtPath:error:) I can't determine what ErrorTypes `removeItemAtPath` might throw.

I realize I can resolve this issue by nesting do blocks, but that will quickly become a nested mess.

So, **how do I determine what error is thrown from a specific try statement in do block with multiple try statements?**

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    try thingOne()
    try thingTwo()
    try manager.removeItemAtPath("myPath") //NSFileManager instance
} catch ThingOneErrorType.SomeError {
    //code here
} catch let error as NSError { 
    //Need to respond explicitly to manager.removeItemAtPath but how?
    print("Error: \(error.domain)")
}
```

probably

```
} catch NSCocoaError.FileNoSuchFileError {
    print("Error: no such file exists")
}
```

would works in your case ... (i didn't check it!!). error.domain will help you to recognize it

you can recognize which statement throws the error by using an 'extra' statement, or better with help of successful return from your throwing funcion. what we can to say about this approach? you are better to redesign you code. error handling should be used as error handling, not as part of your program flow.

```
import Foundation
struct E: ErrorType{}
func foo() throws -> Void {
    let r = random() % 3
    if r == 0 {
        throw E()
    }
}
var fail = 0
do {
    try foo()
    fail++
    try foo()
    fail++
    try foo()
    fail++
} catch let e as E {
    print("failed in :",fail, "attempt")
}
```

// fail in : 2 attempt

Comment: And if I had multiple try statements each of which could potentially throw the same type of error or there were methods with a large number of possible errors that could be thrown? What I then HAVE to nest my do statements?

Comment: if more than one of your statements could throw the same error, do you really need another action in you code? hm ... in that case, you have to use separated do/try/catch block ...